# ZwMapViewOfSection: error 0xc0000017 (to ntoskrnl.exe) and 0xc0000604 (to win32k.sys)

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, kernel-module

I'm want get **base address** (not confuse with **image base**) directly from two kernel modules (files) and the following code works 100% from Win XP to Win 7 x32.

These errors occurs when i try to map *ntoskrnl.exe* or *win32k.sys* on Win 8.1 (still not tested in Win 10).

To *ntoskrnl.exe* comes **0xc0000017** and with *win32k.sys* ( with `KeStackAttachProcess` to *csrss.exe* process, (not tested without `KeStackAttachProcess`) comes **0xc0000604** (undocumented error) ).

How fix?

```
#define SEC_IMAGE 0x1000000

   ///////////////////////////// VARIABLES ///////////////////////////////////

    CHAR buf[MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH]="\\SystemRoot\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe";
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oaNtoskrnl,oa;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK stStatusBlock;
    HANDLE hNtoskrnl=0,hSection=0;
    UNICODE_STRING us;
    PVOID pNtoskrnl=0;
    ULONG dwViewSize=0;
    STRING as;

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        RtlInitString(&as,(PCSZ)buf);
        RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&us,&as,TRUE);

        DbgPrint("%wZ", &us);

        InitializeObjectAttributes(&oaNtoskrnl,&us,OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE|OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,NULL,NULL);

        status=ZwCreateFile(
        &hNtoskrnl,
        FILE_READ_DATA,
        &oaNtoskrnl,
        &stStatusBlock,
        NULL,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        FILE_OPEN,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    RtlFreeUnicodeString(&us);

    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Failed ZwCreateFile! 0x%x \n", status);
    }

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa,NULL,OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE|OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,NULL,NULL);

    status=ZwCreateSection(
        &hSection,
        SECTION_MAP_READ,
        &oa,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READONLY,
        SEC_IMAGE,
        hNtoskrnl
        );
    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint(("Failed ZwCreateSection! 0x%x \n", status));
        ZwClose(hNtoskrnl);
    }

    status=ZwMapViewOfSection(
        hSection,
        NtCurrentProcess(),
        &pNtoskrnl,
        16,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &dwViewSize,
        ViewUnmap,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE
        );

    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Failed ZwMapViewOfSection! 0x%x \n", status);
        ZwClose(hSection);
        ZwClose(hNtoskrnl);
    }

    DbgPrint("Initialize finished! 0x%x \n", pNtoskrnl); 

    ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), pNtoskrnl);
    ZwClose(hSection);
    ZwClose(hNtoskrnl);
```

**EDIT:**

After suggestions here is part changed, but still with same trouble (now tested also on Win 10).

```
ULONG modsz = 0; // receives size of file after execute MyEnumKernelModule()

MyEnumKernelModule("\\systemroot\\system32\\win32k.sys",&ModuleAddress, &modsz);

status=ZwCreateSection(
        &hSection,
        SECTION_ALL_ACCESS,
        &oa,
        (PLARGE_INTEGER)modsz,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
        SEC_COMMIT,
        hNtoskrnl
        );

status=ZwMapViewOfSection(
        hSection,
        NtCurrentProcess(),
        &pNtoskrnl,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &modsz,
        ViewUnmap,
        MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
        );
```

Comment: You are specifying NULL for the AllocationType parameter.  But if I'm reading the ZwMapViewOfSection docs correct (and the VirtualAlloc docs to which they refer) that parameter is not supposed to be zero but rather one of several values (e.g. MEM_COMMIT, MEM_RESERVE, etc).  Try reading those docs and supplying  whatever value for those flags you think best corresponds to your situation

Comment: `ZeroBits == 16 -> STATUS_NO_MEMORY` . create section with `PAGE_READONLY` and try map it with `PAGE_READWRITE` ?!?. `STATUS_DYNAMIC_CODE_BLOCKED` also well known and documented error. executable code (`SEC_IMAGE`) can not be writable

Comment: I not found any documentation official of Microsoft about **0xc0000604**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error codes:

- Error code: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000017 (3221225495) - {Not Enough Quota}  Not enough virtual memory or paging file quota is available to complete the specified operation.
- Error code: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000604 (3221227012) - **The operation was blocked as the process prohibits dynamic code generation.**

Seems like a process restriction based on the error.

Comment: and why the same code works fine on Win 7 and possibly no Win 8? i not understood it.

Comment: I made some changes, but still continue with same trouble, see my edition above. Sincerelly i think that `ZwMapViewOfSection()` not is recomended to use on Win 8.1 and higther.

Comment: you mistake. `STATUS_NO_MEMORY` exactly because OP by unknown reason (why and for what he don't know) use `ZeroBits == 16`. also many another errors in code. `STATUS_DYNAMIC_CODE_BLOCKED` because `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` used and process disabled dynamic code generation

Comment: @RbMm, you saw my edition? i changed exactly where was suggested, but still continue the same trouble.

Comment: @JoãoPablo - you continue nothing understand. all

Comment: @RbMm, I only not understad is why must be a different code to Win 8.1 and 10 :-). Why?

Comment: @JoãoPablo - code must be the **same** from xp to win10. i only not understand why you do so huge count of errors. you are mistaken wherever possible and impossible. the whole code is a solid error

Comment: @RbMm, then all suggestions here not are relevant. Ex: was suggested to create section with read/write flag and even so still the result is same.

Comment: And also this my edit above was based in other code that you posted here in S.O. Have you sure that is able to map *ntoskrnl.exe* or *win32k.sys* with sucess on Win 8.1 and higther?